# In C++, on object creation, is new used implicitly?

Tags: c++, oop

When I create an object of a class, say,

```
class A {
  public: A() {}
};

A a;
```

Is only the constructor called? Or is it that the `new` operator is used implicitly?

Like we have to do `A* b = new A();`

Also, where will `a` and `b` be stored in memory? Stack or heap?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first case, if `a` is not a global variable, then it will be put on the stack, while `b` will be put on the heap.

And in the first case, only the constructor is called. `new` is never called except if you do it explicitly as in the second case.

Comment: No, that's just a really bad thing.

Comment: @sTEAK. Only if `A` has a constructor which accepts a pointer to itself as an argument (which, btw., is not a copy-constructor), and copies the data from it. But then you will have a memory leak as the object allocated by `new` can't be free'd later.

Comment: As an addendum, globals would usually be stored in the .data/bss of the binary - on neither the heap nor the stack - on most systems.

Answer (score 6):

No `new` is not called implicitly. `new` returns a pointer to the type of object created whereas a constructor call does not have a return type. Objects created with `new` will exist on the heap. New will allocate memory, then call the constructor. Objects created in the form `A a` will exist on the stack (unless they are global variables).